# Splash screen taking longer than it should

Tags: android, user-interface, splash-screen, lag

I have a splash screen that contains only a `TextView` and the duration of this splash screen is 500ms. But my splash screen takes around 4 seconds to finish and go to the main activity. If I remove the splash screen, the `MainActivity` itself takes 4-5seconds to show the contents. `MainActivity` contains a `custom background(image from drawable - 1280x720)`, a `tablayout with 6 tabs`. Each tab contains `recyclerview` with texts and images. When the `MainActivity` is opened, all the views appear after a split second. So basically, my UI is lagging a bit. After the `MainActivity`is set, everything works fine. Note: this happens only in oreo. In nougat and below, the splash takes around 1second and `MainActivity`loads fine.

What is the problem I'm facing?

Splash screen:

```
public class splash extends BaseActivity {



private String[] permissionsRequired = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

    checkUserPermission();

}




public void DisplaySplashScreen() {


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    }, 500);

}



private void checkUserPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permissionsRequired[2])!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permissionsRequired[3])!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.CAMERA},123);
            return;
        }
    }

    DisplaySplashScreen();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 123:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(splash.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DisplaySplashScreen();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Needs permission to go ahead", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUserPermission();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the Hugo library from Jake Wharton to figure out which function is taking a long time to execute. https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

Comment: please post your onCreate method from your MainActivity!

Comment: Sure! just a sec.

Comment: just a small hint always use CamelCase and especially for your class names :) so make it Splash instead of splash, of course this has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: That is something new, good to know. Thanks! :)

Comment: Posted mainactivity's oncreate!

Comment: i can see nothing that causes this behavior maybe soemthing in your setUpMenu or setupViewPager;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169142/discussion-between-yamen-nassif-and-rektirino).

Comment: were you able to fix this ? if yes how ?

Comment: I just downgraded from oreo(custom rom) to nougat and it is working fine. Tested on couple of  other roms and it is working fine. I don't know something is just not working right with oreo.

Comment: @YamenNassif I think I found out the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Need your help!

Comment: @Rektirino i send a message on the previous discussion see it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of stuff happening in your MainActivity's onCreate method. That can easily cause slowness in your app.

The best option is to put your time taking tasks in background thread.

Comment: But then why the time difference in oreo and nougat? Both should have same execution time. Both the android device I'm using have the same  specs.

Comment: But again it depends on device's processing

Answer (score 0):

Performance differs from Android version to version. In your case, there can be 2 reasons-

1. Check the API response time in both the devices (ideally it should
   be same)
2. The most common reason for slowing down is that you are using some component or code which is compatible with low version and does
   not support with the higher version.

Comment: I'll try updating the libraries!

Answer (score 0):

After reading rest of the code i can't see anything that causes this behavior, so I would suggest that you comment all the code from MainActivity and just try to load an empty one after the splash screen, then if it was still slow it will be 100% APIs that you use, if it got fixed then go and uncomment your code piece by piece until it gets slow again then you will be able to know which part of the code caused this slow. Finding the problem can be tricky sometimes but once you find it it's easier to solve.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll try to find what is wrong. Will get back to you asap!